# #1064 SQL syntax;

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong, here?
When I run the statement without "CREATE VIEW [Bookings_View] AS"
It works fine and brings back what is needed.

```
 CREATE VIEW [Bookings_View] AS
 SELECT Customer.First_Name,Customer.Last_Name,Vehicles.Make,
 Vehicles.Model,Bookings.Pick_Up_Date, Bookings.Return_Date,Bookings.Booking_Id
 FROM Bookings
 INNER JOIN Vehicles ON Bookings.Vehicle_Id = Vehicles.Vehicle_Id
 JOIN Customer ON Bookings.Customer_Id = Customer.Customer_Id
```

> Error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[Bookings_View] AS SELECT Customer.First_Name,Customer.Last_Name,Vehicles.Make,' at line 1

Thank You.

Comment: MySQL does not use `[ ]` in escaping but rather backtick `\``.

Comment: @今草顿웃: and neither of them are SQL standard - the standard double quotes `"` should be preferred in any case.

Comment: Better still, just say `CREATE VIEW Bookings_View` because there is no need for quoting at all.

Comment: wow, didnt even know ` existed, worked a treat. I was using ' instead, and was always wondering, Why?

Comment: this is where I learning from http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp They use [], strange?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I agree =)

Comment: Every DBMS uses a slightly different delimiter. The brackets are used by MS SQL.

Comment: @user3054912: don't use w3schools as a reference (especially if you want a reference for the SQL *standard) - that website is full of errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL uses backticks (`` ` ``) instead of brackets (`[]`).  Your sql statement should state

```
CREATE VIEW `Bookings_View` AS
SELECT Customer.First_Name,Customer.Last_Name,Vehicles.Make,
Vehicles.Model,Bookings.Pick_Up_Date, Bookings.Return_Date,Bookings.Booking_Id
FROM Bookings
INNER JOIN Vehicles ON Bookings.Vehicle_Id = Vehicles.Vehicle_Id
JOIN Customer ON Bookings.Customer_Id = Customer.Customer_Id
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use brackets for escaping. Use nothing or backtiks(``).

```
CREATE VIEW Bookings_View
CREATE VIEW `Bookings_View`
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use **backtick** instead of `[]`

Use,

```
CREATE VIEW `Bookings_View` AS
```

instead of

```
CREATE VIEW [Bookings_View] AS
```

Answer (score 0):

try this ... (use backticks for escape character)

```
CREATE VIEW `Bookings_View` AS
SELECT Customer.First_Name,Customer.Last_Name,Vehicles.Make,
Vehicles.Model,Bookings.Pick_Up_Date, Bookings.Return_Date,Bookings.Booking_Id
FROM Bookings
INNER JOIN Vehicles ON Bookings.Vehicle_Id = Vehicles.Vehicle_Id
JOIN Customer ON Bookings.Customer_Id = Customer.Customer_Id
```